# setting status bar font color to black in certain views iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the answers on other questions aren't working. I want my app to have light text on all views except for 3. I set the plist key to `NO`, and I have `Status Bar Style` in Deployment Info in General settings set to light. In the few screens I want to have black status bar font, I added

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.Default
}
```

Straight from Apple's UIApplication

```
public enum UIStatusBarStyle : Int {

    case Default // Dark content, for use on light backgrounds
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    case LightContent // Light content, for use on dark backgrounds
}
```

So why is the override function not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `preferredStatusBarStyle`, you have to put `View controller-based status bar appearance` to YES in `info.plist`, but better try use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(.Default, animated: false)` on `viewDidLoad` of screen you want to be black, and set back to `.LightContent` in its `viewDidDisapear`, this way is easier and cleaner

Comment: This doesn't work, this just makes everything black. If I use your .setStatusBarStyle, is it still YES in the plist? Also I get depreciation warnings to use preferredStatusBarStyle

Comment: if you use `setStatusBarStyle `, it should be NO in the .plist

Comment: btw, try call `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() ` and set some breakpoint and see if the line got called or not if you doing the first way